# OBJC Another crash log issue

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I've been scanning thru similar questions but I cannot find one that applies to my case or clear enough. My app was rejected by the Apple Review with it crashes al launch, it works on all of my devices the crashlog is as below , the uuid matches on DSYM and the binary section on the crash log, ran atos, dwarf , symbolicate and all of the suggested stuff on the other questions but I get nothing it just echoes back the addresses or prints it back so i cannot find out where/what causes the crash. Any suggestion??? I also found a bunch of perl/csh scripts that do the same or fail so I'm stuck.

```
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [840]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/772689C2-24B8-49E8-A236- 
C0D669C5A5AE/MyApp.app/MyApp
Version:             4   (1.40)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Date/Time:           2018-07-25 08:49:09.6233 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-07-25 08:49:04.7929 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    6.80.00
Report Version:      104    


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000dc17cbec8
VM Region Info: 0xdc17cbec8 is not in any region.  Bytes after 
previous region: 51027689161  
  REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] 
PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
  MALLOC_NANO (reserved) 00000001d8000000-00000001e0000000 [128.0M] 
rw-/rwx SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
--->  
  UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183fcd7f4 0x183fa8000 + 
153588
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cc6500 0x184cb1000 + 87296
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183fce13c 0x183fa8000 + 155964
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbcaac 0x184cb1000 + 47788
4   UIKit                           0x000000018ede35c8 0x18e9bf000 + 4343240
5   UIKit                           0x000000018edfb9dc 0x18e9bf000 + 4442588
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9e910 0x184cb1000 + 973072
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9c238 0x184cb1000 + 963128
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184d9c884 0x184cb1000 + 964740
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000184cbcda8 0x184cb1000 + 48552
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186ca2020 0x186c97000 + 45088
11  UIKit                           0x000000018ecdc758 0x18e9bf000 + 3266392
12  MyApp                           0x00000001011bd888 main (main.m:14)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018474dfc0 0x18474d000 + 4032

Thread 1:
```